# AngularJS directive not applied even though the naming convention is correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my directive:

```
angApp.directive('stopPropagation', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',            
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                console.log(elem);
                $(elem).click(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

and this is my HTML code:

```
<form stop-propagation>
</form>
```

The `console.log` is never fired. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you put this in a JSFiddle?

Comment: did you include the correct app

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u4NZy/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `ng-app` and `ng-controller` to wire everything together:

```
<div ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="AppController">
  <form stop-propagation>
    {{message}}
  </form>
</div>
```

See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/u4NZy/2/